# How do I get this circle get in the center of the box?

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I am studying game programming and I cracked my head over the exercise but I can`t get this circle stopped in the center of the box in the update function.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var circleX = 100;
var circleY = 100;
var circleR =  50;
var circleC =  'yellow';
var circleSpeedX =  65;
var circleSpeedY =  45;

var rectX = 650;
var rectY = 450;
var rectW = 110;
var rectH = 110;
var rectC = 'red';

function clear()
{
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function drawRect(rectX,rectY,rectW,rectH,rectC)
{
    context.fillStyle = rectC;
    context.fillRect(rectX,rectY,rectW,rectH);
}   

function drawCircle(circleX,circleY,circleR,circleC)
{
    context.fillStyle = circleC;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(circleX,circleY,circleR,0,2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = 'orange';
    context.fill();
}

    function update()
    {

    }

function draw()
{
    clear();
    drawRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,'black');
    drawRect(rectX,rectY,rectW,rectH,rectC);
    drawCircle(circleX,circleY,circleR,circleC);
}

function loop()
{
    update();
    draw(rectX, rectY, circleX, circleY);
    setTimeout(loop, 30);
}

loop();
```

Comment: The condition `circleR == rectX/2` is not true when you start... you're not modifying the value of either `circleR` or `rectX` anywhere in the program.  How can that ever become true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azurelogic/QJ6kF/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var circleX = 100;
var circleY = 100;
var circleR =  50;
var circleC =  'yellow';
var circleSpeedX =  6.5;
var circleSpeedY =  4.5;

var rectX = 200;
var rectY = 200;
var rectW = 110;
var rectH = 110;
var rectC = 'red';

function clear()
{
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function drawRect(rectX,rectY,rectW,rectH,rectC)
{
    context.fillStyle = rectC;
    context.fillRect(rectX,rectY,rectW,rectH);
}   

function drawCircle(circleX,circleY,circleR,circleC)
{
    context.fillStyle = circleC;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(circleX,circleY,circleR,0,2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = 'orange';
    context.fill();
}

    function update()
    {
        if (circleY > rectX && circleX < rectX + rectW &&
            circleY > rectY && circleY < rectY + rectH){
            circleSpeedX = circleSpeedY = 0;
            rectC = 'GREEN';
        }
        else {
            circleX += circleSpeedX; 
            circleY += circleSpeedY;
        }
    }

function draw()
{
    clear();
    drawRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,'black');
    drawRect(rectX,rectY,rectW,rectH,rectC);
    drawCircle(circleX,circleY,circleR,circleC);
}

function loop()
{
    update();
    draw();
    setTimeout(loop, 30);
}

loop();
```